# Synchronous and asynchronous terminology when talking about sockets

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, network-programming, terminology

I do not fully understand what does it mean when they say something like: "**asynchronous** read and write operations" or "**synchronous** read and write operations".

I will give examples to demonstrate my understanding of the terminology and correct if I am wrong:

- Read and write on a socket in a blocking mode is considered synchronous.
- Read and write on a socket in a non-blocking mode is considered asynchronous.
- Read and write on a socket using Overlapped I/O is considered asynchronous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Read and write on a socket in a blocking mode is considered synchronous.

Yes.

> Read and write on a socket in a non-blocking mode is considered asynchronous.

No. It is synchronous. The operation completes or fails inline in the current thread.

> Read and write on a socket using Overlapped I/O is considered asynchronous.

Correct. The function call posts the operation to be done, which proceeds independently of the current thread, and a later operation is required to determine its success or failure, or there is a completion callback.

Answer (score 2):

No.  An operation on a non-blocking socket is synchronous.

In Windows, "overlapped I/O" is a synonym for "asynchronous I/O".

Answer (score 0):

I think of it as relating to the calling thread of execution.

Synchronous means that the calling thread of execution is 'in sync' with the operation. So when the call returns, the calling thread has the data from the operation available to use.

Asynchronous means that the calling thread of execution is **not** in sync with the operation. So when the calling thread returns from the operation, It might have data from the operation or it might not; it needs to deal with both cases.

Comment: His definition for non-blocking I/O *isn't* correct according to your explanation.

Comment: I'm not seeing it. Why isn't it?

Comment: When a non-blocking call returns, the calling thread has the data from the operation available to use, or an error. Either way the call is complete. In async I/O the operation is definitely not complete when the call returns; you have to call something else or await the completion callback. Your definition of that needs a little work, but either way it doesn't admit of non-blocking I/O being considered asynchronous.

Comment: Whenever any call returns, the call is complete. The difference is what happens in that call. Maybe I'm conflating synchronicity and blocking, but if a call guarantees that it doesn't block I wouldn't call it asynchronous.

Comment: I should have said 'either way the *operation* is complete'.